# Caching Server OS X Port

Tags: macos, network, server.app

When you run sudo fullstatus caching, it lists all the relevant data for how the caching works on the server. There is one particular line that shows what port the caching server is using.

Does this port need to be open and accessible in order for caching to work properly? For example, does this port need to be forwarded/opened since we are NAT'ed in order for caching to work (because caching doesn't seem to be working right now even though it says that it is running)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does need opening if you are trying to access your Caching server outside of your network. If you are only attempting to access it within the network, this port doesn't need unblocking externally.

Comment: Here's a follow up question, what exactly is that port used for on the caching server? Is it used for Apple to communicate back to the caching server or for the clients internally to communicate with the caching server?

Comment: @user41798 It's used by the clients to communicate with the Caching server. The Caching server uses that port with Apple's servers too but that doesn't require any special network configuration to work.